# Save excel worksheet to a folder and filename based on cell values

Tags: excel

I am trying to save a copy of a worksheet to a specific folder based on cell H3 and name the .xlsx file based on the cell range F2 too. I am using the following code to save a copy of the worksheet to a folder. Just can't get it to work. I get an error code.

Here is the code I am using:

```
  Const MYPATH As String = "R:\Sales\Quotes (Commercial)\"

Sub IfNewFolder()

'Dim part1 As String 'this variable is not used -----
Dim part3 As String  'Company Name
Dim part4 As String 'Folder Name
'----- Dim FolderCreate As String  'this variable is not used -----

'----- part1 = Range("E4").Value 'not used here -----
part3 = Range("D1").Value
part4 = Range("J2").Value

If Len(Dir(MYPATH & part3 & part4, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir MYPATH & part3 & part4
End If

End Sub
Sub SaveFileFolder()

Dim part1 As String
Dim part3 As String
Dim part4 As String

part1 = Range("F2").Value 'Quote Number
part3 = Range("D1").Value 'Company Name
part4 = Range("J2").Value 'Folder Name


IfNewFolder 'create company subfolder

'ChDir MYPATH ' From what I've read on the internet, this is telling excel to save files to this directory...
'-----you don't have to do that because this path is included in the filename in the SaveAs below -----

' Creates file to directory Customers. But I can't get it to recognize the new folder created in the sub above...

'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
 MYPATH & part1 & "_" & part3 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
 xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

'----- instead put company in path (point to company subfolder) -----
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= _
MYPATH & part3 & part4 & "\" & part1 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:= _
xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False


End Sub
```

Comment: what error message are you getting, and at what line?

Comment: At the very least, I think you need a colon, no? Are you on Windows or Mac? `...SaveAs "R:\Sales\..."`?

Comment: I put the colon in but it does not save it to the folder that is listed in the cell H3.

Comment: Are you sure the `If` statements are structured as you want? Why is 2/3 of the code within the `Else` block?

Comment: I got to work doing it with another approach.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: the error message I get is path not fond. If you have a better what of writing this code please let me know.